# how to add $ sign before the variable value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i have variable in HTML which stores values 835 i want that befor 835 there shoud be $ showing like this with value $835.

```
same_vaccination_severeei_unvaccinated_val_1.value =  ((parseFloat(mixed_population_ci_unvaccinated_val_1.value) * parseFloat(if_influenza_severe_unvaccinated_val_1.value)/10000)*100).toFixed(2) + $;
```

Comment: As a side issue, I'd strongly recommend splitting your long lines into smaller lines and using temporary variables to hold your results. This will aid in legibility.

Comment: Also, this won't work as it stands if your values `mixed_population_ci_unvaccinated_val_1.value` don't contain numeric values. Even though you're calling parseFloat, you're trying to do multiple these values (which may be nothing)

Comment: You really should try to read some docs on javascript. Keywords: "what is a string" and "how to join strings"

Comment: @Muleskinner its ok but why you downvoted this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
same_vaccination_severeei_unvaccinated_val_1.value = '$' + ((parseFloat(mixed_population_ci_unvaccinated_val_1.value) * parseFloat(if_influenza_severe_unvaccinated_val_1.value)/10000)*100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
same_vaccination_severeei_unvaccinated_val_1.value = "$"+((parseFloat(mixed_population_ci_unvaccinated_val_1.value) * parseFloat(if_influenza_severe_unvaccinated_val_1.value)/10000)*100).toFixed(2);
```